# How to give a link for bootstrap-tabs from another page

Tags: html

I want to give a link for nav-tabs from another page. I mean to say that, I want to access nav-tabs from another page. I will give you the detailed information about it.

On my website there are two pages one is index.html page and another is a business-listing.html. In business-listing page I used nav-tabs. And I want to access these tabs from index.html page.

Give some idea how to give a link.

The code is too long, so I can't put it here.

I'm trying this code to give a link `<a href="business-listing.html#tab-id">Link to Tab1</a>`, but it can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd need to write some JavaScript code to make this work. The tab switching occurs when you click on a navbar link. Something like:

```
$(function () {

    var tabId = window.location.hash;

    $("#yourTabUl").find('a[href=' + tabId + ']').tab('show');

});
```

Replace `yourTabUl` with the `ìd` of your `ul`-element of the TabLinks. (Create an id if needed)

Also see the documentation here: https://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

Comment: @Saurav if it worked, please upvote and accept my answer

Comment: Yeah, sure, I'm waiting for the time limit for accepting your answer.